# Scala compilation issue "forward reference extends over definition of value"

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-2.13

Compilation error occurs for the below snippet only when it is method level implementation and error does not occur when it is defined in main.  What is the difference ? Scala version used is 2.13.5.

```scala
class FibonacciGenerator  {
  def generate(total: Int): List[Int] = {
    val fibSeries: LazyList[Int] = LazyList.cons(1, LazyList.cons(1, fibSeries.zip(fibSeries.tail).map { t => t._1 + t._2 }))
    fibSeries.take(total).toList
  }
}
```

Same implementation does not fail below.

```scala
object Misc extends App {

  val x: LazyList[Int] = LazyList.cons(1, LazyList.cons(1, x.zip(x.tail).map{t => t._1 + t._2}))
  println(x)
  println(x.take(10).toList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the latter case you are using objects which are created [lazily](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)

> An object... is created lazily when it is referenced, like a lazy val.

In the first case it should work if you declare `lazy val fibSeries`.